# Fourier transform of a convolution - differentiabilty

Tags: continuity, fourier-analysis, convolution, fourier-transform

I am not sure how to prove this property of Fourier transforms:

Two functions that have compact support and are continuous  $ f, g \in C_c(\mathbb R)$ and therefore the Fourier transform of their convolution is infintely differentiable,
 $$ \widehat {f*g} \in C^\infty(\mathbb R).$$

I tried writing the whole integral down - but I think that I am missing a certain property of functions with compact support. Any tip/idea on how to approach this problem is welcome.

Comment: See the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2620565/question-about-the-fourier-transform-of-ln1x2-exp-x2/2620900#2620900) for the basic result you're missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the [Paley-Wiener theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley%E2%80%93Wiener_theorem), the Fourier transform of a continuous and compact-supported function is much more than $C^\infty$: it is an entire function with finite order. The space of such functions is closed with respect to $\cdot$ and $\widehat{f*g}=\widehat{f}\cdot \widehat{g}$.